# Crashlytics not working on older device

Tags: android, crashlytics

I've been working on an app for a few months now on my Nexus 5, but have recently started testing it out on older devices. When I test it on my Galaxy Nexus (GSM) and the app crashes, I'm not getting a report from Crashlytics. When I check the logs, I get this output:

```
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283): Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/[APP.PACKAGE.NAME]/settings
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283): io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1392)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.stream(HttpRequest.java:1665)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.buffer(HttpRequest.java:1654)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.body(HttpRequest.java:1577)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.body(HttpRequest.java:1591)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:65)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:63)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:47)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:139)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:80)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:26)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit$InitializationTask.doInBackground(Kit.java:219)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit$InitializationTask.doInBackground(Kit.java:189)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:294)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:143)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:226)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.header(HttpRequest.java:1913)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.parameter(HttpRequest.java:2005)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.charset(HttpRequest.java:2111)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     ... 16 more
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
11-14 16:42:29.435: E/Fabric(8283):     ... 33 more
```

Everything works great (in terms of reporting) on my Nexus 5, what would be happening that my Galaxy Nexus can't when using the same app?

Here is the full log from launch to crash (with private information removed): http://pastebin.com/9v90Cpws

Comment: are there any logs after `Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED` ? Could you post them

Comment: I posted the full log, any ideas?

Comment: why don't you contact crashlytics support for this ?

Comment: I have but i haven't heard back and was going someone else had some insight.

Comment: Are you sure the device is connected to the internet?

Comment: It is, before the app reaches it's crash it connects to an API to sync some data for the actual app.